# multi left join sql - optimize table schema or sql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

this is my sql and it is too slow, plz tell me how to optimize my table schema or this sql

```sql
SELECT 
    activityLog.id, activityLog.business_id, activityLog.business_typedict.label, 
    dict.id, callLog.id, callLog.duration, callLog.record_url, 
    leads.name AS "leads.name", customer.name AS "customer.name", 
    niche.name AS "niche.name", contacts.name AS "contacts.name", 
    task.name AS "task.name" 
FROM 
    biz_business_log activityLog 
    LEFT JOIN leads_leads leads 
        ON activityLog.business_type=1 AND activityLog.business_id=leads.id 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_office 
                      WHERE 1 = 1 AND (id = '5' OR parent_ids LIKE '5,%') 
                          AND id=leads.office_id) 
    LEFT JOIN cust_customer customer 
        ON activityLog.business_type=2 AND activityLog.business_id=customer.id 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_office 
                      WHERE 1 = 1 AND (id = '5' OR parent_ids LIKE '5,%') 
                          AND id=customer.office_id) 
    LEFT JOIN niche_niche niche 
        ON activityLog.business_type=3 AND activityLog.business_id=niche.id 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_office 
                      WHERE 1 = 1 AND (id = '5' OR parent_ids LIKE '5,%') 
                          AND id=niche.office_id) 
    LEFT JOIN contacts_contacts contacts 
        ON activityLog.business_type=4 AND activityLog.business_id=contacts.id 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_office 
                      WHERE 1 = 1 AND (id = '5' OR parent_ids LIKE '5,%') 
                          AND id=contacts.office_id) 
    LEFT JOIN task_task task 
        ON activityLog.business_type=5 AND activityLog.business_id=task.id 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_office 
                      WHERE 1 = 1 AND (id = '5' OR parent_ids LIKE '5,%') 
                          AND id=task.office_id) 
    LEFT JOIN sys_dict dict 
        ON activityLog.activity_log_type = dict.value 
    LEFT JOIN biz_call_log callLog 
        ON callLog.business_log_id = activityLog.id 
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND dict.type='activity_log_type' 
    AND dict.company_id = 2 
    AND activityLog.company_id = 2 
    AND dict.delete_flag = 0 
ORDER BY
    IFNULL(activityLog.update_time, activityLog.create_time) DESC 
LIMIT 
    0,20
```

explain:
[image]

Comment: You need to give s some stats like table size & structure of the involved tables + indexes Also.. why the 1=1 in the where?
Is the column activityLog.company_id indexed?

Comment: You tagged your question with both PostgreSQL and MySQL, yet the execution plan is MySQL. Which database are you actually using? This query (which looks like it's been generated by a (not so nice) ORM) can be heavily improved by using a CTE, which is supported by PostgreSQL, but not MySQL (as of version 5.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because dict no use index and using temporary